# how to search for multiple strings in multiple columns in ORACLE SQL where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

My situation - I have to two tables with several columns each, and I need to find certain strings in certain columns in those two tables. For example the search string could be 'ExampleString1' , 'ExampleString2%' etc around 20 strings and about 5 - 6 columns in each table.

I m using the following to find atleast one string in the multiple columns, but this even is not working.

```
select * from table1 a where upper('ExampleString1%') in (a.Column1, a.column2, a.column3)
```

Although I can do some basic sql queries, I m not that acquaint with sql. I like to know the solution or any material I can study to get to solution.

Thanks
rK

Comment: If you're trying to use `%` as a wildcard, that syntax doesn't work. `%` works with `LIKE`, not `IN`, and it's on the wrong side of the operator anyway.

Comment: What's wrong with multiple like and ors?

Answer (score 3):

You can combine all required fields and run a check on that:

```
select * 
from table1 a
where NVL(upper(a.Column1),'')||NVL(upper(a.column2),'')||NVL(upper(a.column3),'') like upper('ExampleString1%')
```

Comment: Do you need to use `||` to concatenate instead? I wasn't aware `+` would work here.

Comment: Don't forget to use to_upper on the lhs of the predicate.

Comment: @McGlothlin: Updated my answer. Used to be a SQL-Server developer :)

Comment: No worries! It said you deleted it... glad you didn't because it was mostly right. One upvote for you.

Comment: If you to_upper the concatenation instead of the concatenated elements, it will make for better factoring.

Comment: Don't forget to tell the OP that this statement's response time is proportional to the size of the table. Indexing this would be a nightmare. I'd recommend some other text solution unless this is going to be a *very* infrequent occurring business task on the production environment.

Comment: Why would you use `upper()` on a nonbound `like` statement (right hand side)? . Just capitalize it in the query. If you're using a bound parameter, do the conversion in the program logic. `upper()` in that placement creates a lot of unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @Jacobm001: OP was trying to do the same thing. This parameter could be from user input which OP doesn't have control over.

Comment: This query doesn't give desired results (doesn't return a row) where for example a row contains:  column1=`ABC`, column2=`ExampleString1`, column3=`XYZ`.

Comment: This query will give false matches, too. If you search for `ExampleString1` you may have `Example` in column1 and `String1` in column2, when you concatenate them you get `ExampleString1`.

Comment: @mathguy: As per OP, parameter will be `ExampleString1`, `ExampleString2`, etc. For multiple parameters, this check has to be done separately.

Answer (score 0):

The use of upper() can be avoided here by using REGEXP_LIKE

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE A WHERE 
REGEXP_LIKE(COLUMN1 || COLUMN2 || COLUMN3, '<search expression>', 'i')
```

Comment: This query might return rows where columns don't mach the expression that is searched for. eg.: COLUMN1 = "panic", COLUMN2 = "order", search expression = "cord", no column matches the search, but when you concatenate you will get "pani**cord**er" and this row will get incorrectly returned.